# Bootstrap inference

Tags: statistical-significance, bootstrap, resampling

I got a historical set of returns and use them on different investment strategies. From each of these strategies i calculate some measures like terminal wealth, growth rate etc.

Now to get a sense of how significant these results are I made a block bootstrap of the returns and formed groups à 100 bootstrap samples, where I calculate the performance measures for each and do that 1000 times. So I get 1000 times an estimator for terminal wealth, growth rate etc.

Afterwards I take the differences of two strategies in each estimator and calculate the confidence intervals with regular confidence level. Now, if the zero is not in the CI I can conclude that the difference is significant.

But what exactly is significant? The differences in the performance measure from the original historical data, or the differences of the bootstrapped returns?

What if I have that the original difference is positive, but the CI of the bootsrapped differences include only negative values?